# How to fetch and filter data retrieved from Yahooquery?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

I am trying to retrieve the quarterly earnings of some companies using YahooQuery and I've been able to fetch the data for the whole year but I want to filter this data to show only the specific quarter's results. Furthermore I want to export this data to an Excel sheet and save it there for all the companies.

```
import yahooquery
ticker = yahooquery.Ticker('AAPL',asynchronous=True)
ticker.earnings
```

Below is the output of the code and the highlighted box denotes the quarterly result that I was trying to filter.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar scenario of trying to extract yahooquery's nested dictionaries and found a useful response on a different question which got me on track.

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd

aapl = Ticker('aapl')
aaplInfo = aapl.earnings
```

This is the function code I found on another StackOverflow post

```
def nested_dict_pairs_iterator(dict_obj):
''' This function accepts a nested dictionary as argument
    and iterate over all values of nested dictionaries
'''
# Iterate over all key-value pairs of dict argument
for key, value in dict_obj.items():
    # Check if value is of dict type
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        # If value is dict then iterate over all its values
        for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(value):
            yield (key, *pair)
    else:
        # If value is not dict type then yield the value
        yield (key, value)
```

Here I just pulled out the necessary section you were looking for, and created a pandas dataframe to load into Excel

```
for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(aaplInfo):
    if (pair[1] == 'financialsChart' and pair[2] == 'quarterly'):
        df = pd.DataFrame(pair[3])
        df.to_excel('Stock_Earnings.xlsx', sheet_name='AAPL', index=False)
```